# Load django form instance for form where dropdowns are dependent on each other

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, modelform

I have a ModelForm that has 5 dropdowns on it.

Initially they are shown one dropdown, on user selection (jquery on change event) - Ajax fires off the request to a `view` function - which renders the queryset in a dropdown and is put into the current DOM via jquery.

I [followed this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) to set it up (repeating the process for my 5 dropdowns).

My issue stems when I go to edit a saved form.

Similar to the end of the tutorial, I can setup my form using the instance items and it's ok. If I change the last dropdown and save the form it updates as expected.

But if I change any other item and it generates options that are *not* in the initial queryset, it kicks off errors saying `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`

Should I just generate the queryset again in a `clean_` method for each input and force it to be validated if it matches those?

Is there a better way to handle dependent dropdowns in forms?

My code mimics the tutorial almost exactly - except with a few additional inputs, chained in exactly the same way as the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the `__init__` of the form to utilize the `.is_bound`. method on itself.

By doing that I was able to get it to register the generated querysets as appropriate responses in POST.